# Webpage won't scroll to off-screen elements

Tags: html, scroll

I am working on a webpage where I would like to have multiple fixed elements with the center elements scrolling to reveal the most important information.  However, my page will not enable a scroll bar when an object goes below the screen, and forcing a scroll bar to appear will simply leave an inactive scroll bar on the sides.  I've tried using `html {overflow: auto;}` and other variations to no avail.

The following is my code thus far.  I would like the image at the bottom and the welcome image to scroll up and behind the header, while the side images remain where they are.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!-->Information for the Div's used.</-->
<style>
    .header {position: fixed; top: 5px; right: 6px; height: 120px; width: 100%; background-color: white;}
    .Title {position: fixed; background-color: white; width: 432px; height: 55px; top: 5px; left: 318px;}
    .machine {position: fixed; background-color: white; width: 119px; height: 71px; top: 8px; left: 241px;}
    .bars {position: fixed; background-color: white; width: 981px; height: 56px; top: 90px; left: 9px;}
    .nav {position: fixed; background-color: white; width: 204px; height: 80px; top: 1px; left: 22px;}
    .lborder {position: fixed; background-color: white; width: 193px; height: 518px; top: 145px; left: 16px; }
    .rborder {position: fixed; background-color: white; width: 193px; height: 518px; top: 140px; left: 827px; }
    .welcome {position: absolute; background-color: white; width: 211px; height: 50px; top: 150px; left: 387px; }
    .whitespace {position: absolute; background-color: grey; width: 211px; height: 200px; top: 584px; left: 301px; }
</style>

<!-->Information for font styles. </-->
<style type="text/css">
    .textstyle0 {font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:8pt;text-decoration:none;color:#0000a0;}

</style>
```

```
<!-->This contains all of the objects that will remain static in all pages.
    They will not move when you scroll the page, and are carried over through the whole site. </-->
<div class="header">
    <div class="Title"><img src="files/IMG_5.jpg"</div>
    <div class="machine"><img src="files/IMG_0-test.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="bars"><img src="files/IMG_25.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="nav">  
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2"><span class="textstyle0"><a href="page1.html">About Us</a></span></td>
                <td class="auto-style2"><span class="textstyle0"><a href="Directions.html">Directions</a></span></td>
                <td class="auto-style2"><span class="textstyle0"><a href="default.htm">Home Page</a></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3"><span class="textstyle0"><a href="Contacts.html">Contacts</a></span></td>
                <td class="auto-style3"><span class="textstyle0"><a href="Customers.html">Customers</a></span></td>
                <td class="auto-style3"><span class="textstyle0"><a href=""></a></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="textstyle0"><a href="Products.html">Products</a></span></td>
                <td><span class="textstyle0"><a href="Links.html">Links</a></span></td>
                <td><span class="textstyle0"><a href=""></a></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="textstyle0"><a href="Facilities.html">Facilities</a></span></td>
                <td><span class="textstyle0"><a href="Contact Form.html">Contact Us</a></span></td>
                <td><span class="textstyle0"><a href=""></a></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table></div>
    <div class="lborder"><img src="files/IMG_1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="rborder"><img src="files/IMG_3.jpg" /></div>
</div>

<!-- Scrollable elements -->
<div class="welcome"><img src="files/IMG_7.jpg" /></div>
<div class="whitespace"><img src="files/IMG_34.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: Why are you using tables? Have you considered using external css files?

Comment: I was just using the table for a single navigation window.  though I'm not too familiar with CSS so I might see if that would work better there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a jsfiddle or other code example would help here, but you have a few easy to spot problems -

a) your first image tag for IMG_5 is not closed properly which could cause inconsistent behaviors

b) you're overusing absolute and fixed positioning. I'd try removing all your styles, and adding them back in only where absolutely necessary to get the result you need.

I'd suggest looking at something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) if you're not comfortable with implementing CSS layouts on your own.

I'd also read this article on lists as I think it would be a better solution for the problem it looks like you're trying to solve with tables: http://alistapart.com/article/taminglists/

Comment: a) d'oh, That fixed the problem with the scroll bar not appearing, so there's the immediate problem done, thank you.

b) I'm not quite sure I follow, unless it would be better to not use a positioning variable for items I don't want fixed in place?

I'll look into those links though and post back once I've read through them, that last one in particular looks very interesting at a glance.  Thank you for your help.